# How do I make class variables/methods created and used only when needed?

Tags: python

I'm working on a model that uses player data. During development, only certain data is needed. My thought was to create a `PlayerData` class but my amateur mind doesn't understand/know how to do this properly.

I understand this code is basic, but it's just for example...

```
class PlayerData(object):
    def __init__(self, player_id):
        self.player_id = player_id

    def past_games(self):
        # only if requested, query DB for data

    def vital_info(self):
        # only if requested, query DB for data

    def abilities(self):
        # only if requested, query DB for data

pd = PlayerData(235)
```

If I call `pd.vital_info` for the first time, I only want to execute the query at that point. How do I structure this so the requested query is run while the other queries are not (unless needed later on)?

Comment: if the query is placed inside the function then only the query inside the called function should run

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. Are you concerned that `pd.vital_info` will also cause `pd.abilities` to run?

Comment: @roganjosh thats what i was thinking but couldnt confirm, no matter how many times i read it

Comment: I really struggled writing the question and even edited it a few times. These queries are rather intense and when I only want to analyze some of the data I don't want to unnecessarily call the other datasets.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to assign the data from the query to a variable for use throughout the analytics portion. So every time I reference one of the datasets if it's there it's used, if it's not the query is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should help you understand how functions of a class are called in Python.

```
class PlayerData:

    def __init__(self,player_id):
        print("Calling __init__. Yay!")
        self.player_id = player_id

    def past_games(self):
        print("Calling past_games")
        # only if requested, query DB for data

    def vital_info(self):
        print("Calling vital_info")
        # only if requested, query DB for data

    def abilities(self):
        print("Calling Abilities")
        # only if requested, query DB for data

>> p = PlayerData(1)
Calling __init__. Yay! #No other method was called so you see not print out
>>p.past_games()
Calling past_games
>>p.vital_info()
Calling Vital info
>>p.abilities()
Calling Abilities
```

As you see the class functions need to be explicitly called. There are only a handful of methods that are called when class is initializer. One them is `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything at all. If your queries are in individual methods, then only the methods you actually call will be executed.